# How to get raid of double quotes when dumping a string that includes single quotes

Tags: python, string, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to add single quotes in dumping the following yaml string:

```
yaml_str = 'Type: modified'
```

But the output includes double quotes which are not required.
Here is my code:

```
import sys                                                                                  
import ruamel.yaml                                                                          
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()                                                                                                                                   
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)  
data['Type'] = f"'{data['Type']}'"
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

The output:
`Type: "'modified'"`

The expected output:
`Type: 'modified'`

Any ideas, please?

I tried all kinds of string formatting, nothing helped.
I also tried to add `yaml.preserve_quotes = True` which also didn't do any good.

Comment: try changing `f"'{data['Type']}'"` into `f"{data['Type']}"`

Comment: Why does it matter if the value is quoted or not?

Comment: @Ramesh It doesn't add any single quote. output: `Type: modified`

Comment: @chepner I need it for a file convention. It influences later use in the file.

Comment: Why? What non-YAML operations are you doing with your YAML file?

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is completely wrong, so string formatting is not going to help you at all. YAML, like many other languages need to be able to handle scalars that have embedded quotes and YAML has multiple ways to handle that:

- if a string to be dumped into a scalar has special characters that need backslash escaping (e.g. the audible bell `\a`), the scalar needs to be between double quotes (and double quotes in the string escaped in the scalar)
- if a string to be dumped into a scalar has no special characters, but starts with a double quote, the whole scalar can be single quoted (and any existing single quotes in the string, will need to be duplicated `''` in the scalar)

If you want to force single quotes in ruamel.yaml, even if they are superfluous, you can use:

```
data['Type'] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString('{data['Type']}')
```

although the much better solution would be to get rid of the program that reads your output file and requires the **unnecessary** quotes to be there in the first place.

Please note that having quotes in a string doesn't necessarily require the corresponding scalar to have quotes. E.g. a string that has no spaces and a quote somewhere between normal readable characters can be dumped without (extra) quotes.